# Optimize if statement in C++ using Vector and QDate

Tags: c++, qt, optimization, vector

This if statement is one of my bottlenecks and I am trying to optimize it.
What I am doing is looping through vectors of stock data. This portion is the date and i have to check if its the beginning of a new month then do 'stuff'. Ive optimized most of the rest but this line is really using time and I cannot wrap my head around how to optimize it(relatively new to c++).  I have dummbed down the code but the essentials are there.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The objects are such as this:

```
struct myclass2{
    QDate date;
};
struct myclass1{
    std::vector<myclass2> data;
};
std::vector<myclass1> list1;
```

```
if (list1[j].data[i].date.month() != list1[j].data[i+1].data.month()){ //<==46.9%
//next day is new month,do stuff
}
```

Comment: Precompute the values for all `i` and `j`?

Comment: Did you benchmark optimized build? Else `operator[]` might do extra check.

Comment: cigien I do not understand what you mean by that?  @Jarod42 tried with /Ox and its actually worse at 66.1% now

Comment: too many actions in one line. Split the actions into several different lines and benchmark again

Comment: It's just worse in relation to the total cost probably, not absolute? If you is use QtCreator and QMake, use the "Profile" build type. How big are the lists and how often is the line executed? The line suggests quadratic complexity...

Comment: Just a thought: I sometimes get hints from colleagues that this or that of my code consumes too much time and I had to optimize it. Imagine e.g. something like this trivial: `for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) indices[i] = i;` with the complaint: "Too much time is spent in assigment and vector access." This is what I consider as funny. IMHO, correct would be: "Much time is spent in assignment and vector access." because that is what the code is actually supposed to do. I would become afraid if the opposite would have been observed... Of course, it might be worth to re-think the design in general.